Analysing Documents with LLAVA on Ollama not working
I am currently testing LLAVA for use in Document Understanding Tasks. I found some promissing results in some scientific papers and on some websites. I installed the Model on Ollama (on Windows) and tried accessing it with this C# Code.
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;

public class Program
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    private static string? imageBase64;

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Document Analysis Application!");

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the path to the image file (or 'exit' to quit): ");
            string imagePath;
            do
            {
                imagePath = Console.ReadLine() ?? "";
            } while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(imagePath));

            if (imagePath.ToLower() == "exit")
                break;

            if (!File.Exists(imagePath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File not found. Please try again.");
                continue;
            }

            imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath));
            Console.WriteLine("Image loaded successfully.");

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter your question about the document (or 'new' for a new image, 'exit' to quit): ");
                string question;
                do
                {
                    question = Console.ReadLine() ?? "";
                } while (String.IsNullOrEmpty(question));

                if (question.ToLower() == "new")
                    break;
                if (question.ToLower() == "exit")
                    return;

                Console.WriteLine("Response:");
                _ = await AnalyzeDocument(question);
                Console.WriteLine("\nEnd of response.");
            }
        }
    }

    static async Task<string> AnalyzeDocument(string question)
    {
        var requestBody = new
        {
            model = "llava:13b-v1.6",
            prompt = $"Analyze this invoice image carefully. Pay close attention to all numerical values, especially totals and subtotals. If the question is about a total or sum, make sure to double-check your calculation. After your analysis, provide a clear, concise answer to this specific question: {question}",
            images = new[] { imageBase64 },
            stream = true
        };

        var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestBody), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:11434/api/generate", content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
            {
                StringBuilder fullResponse = new StringBuilder();
                string? line;
                while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) continue;

                    try
                    {
                        using (JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(line))
                        {
                            JsonElement root = doc.RootElement;
                            if (root.TryGetProperty("response", out JsonElement responseElement))
                            {
                                string responsePart = responseElement.GetString() ?? "";
                                fullResponse.Append(responsePart);
                                Console.Write(responsePart); // Print each part as it's received
                            }
                            if (root.TryGetProperty("done", out JsonElement doneElement) && doneElement.GetBoolean())
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (JsonException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Failed to parse JSON: {line}");
                    }
                }
                return fullResponse.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            return $"Error: {e.Message}";
        }
    }
}

Unfortuntely the results are really bad and are mostly hallucinations. Sometimes the LLM complains that it would need a clearer view of the document to answer the questions, i tried downscaling the image, but it still did not work, is there maybe a way to process the image in multiple chunks.

I cannot comment yet so i will be answering instead.
I have tried using Llava for Policies.pdf and stuff for RAG FAQ chatbot, however that multimodal model have also said the same thing to me, either the image is not good enough or it just takes a guess. It is able to understand images though, like dogs, or graphs (in my case it just tells me the image is a graph but cannot give details about it). Even when upscaled with pdf to image to upscaler, it still say the same thing, but can now identify more text on the image.
Ultimately to reach some weird deadline i threw that Model and implemented a pre-processing, PDF to Image to OCR. And yes it makes Llava redundant in here. But you can use other models to process the text output of OCR to reach the same "Document Understanding" task.
Another thing: PDF Documents are a pain, some of them may be all text and can be scraped easily with already available PDFpackages. But some may contain Images, or just all Scanned Images of the actual printed document. That is where Image to OCR will be of use to you. You can try other vision models or OCR packages but currently from all i've tested winocr works best for image text extraction.(yes, its using the OCR engine of windows snipping tool)

Thanks for your input. The problem that i have is that I want to test LLAVAs capability specifically and compare it to the OCR Method you suggested. Researchers of the Article "Robustness of Structured Data Extraction from In-plane Rotated Documents using Multi-Modal Large Language Models" (https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2406.10295) tried this, and had impressive results, but they haven't explained how they worked around this problem.

I checked, It seems they provide structured formats similar to another stuff i've seen, i cannot find it in my history now but they processed their invoices similar with the testing prompts in the article.  However the output json are created after initial adjustments of results from llava. This is an interesting topic i would keep my eyes open for any interesting stuff. Good luck on your tests, :>

Just to be clear: do you mean that they provided the documets to the image by processing it with an OCR Engine and passing it in textual form (with layout information)

Sorry for my confusing way of writing, basically from what i remember they made similar prompts except it encourages the model to output any text it sees in the image, as is and the results are parse in a function that creates the json structure based on expected output, image > llava > text > parser(regex) > structured json. They only showed this for invoices and not any documents (atleast as much as i remember). I said that they provided structured formats because they told it the characteristics of the invoice and how they want the output to look like so they can parse it easily,

I realize by saying "as is" and "provided characteristics for expected output format"  does not make sense, in essence output it in a way with spaces and such but not in tags or encoded,  however their regex only cares about the sequence of characters. so thats probably just to avoid getting unexpected formats in the output, this was a few weeks ago so i can't remember exactly, but if i were to assume maybe they have a process that crops the region of the image and feed that to llava so it only handles little bits of the image at a time, cause i can't think of any other way.
